# Automate click on hyperlink having event listener

Tags: javascript, automation, onclick, dom-events, mouseevent

How to automate click on the hyper link `<a>Reply</a>` using JavaScript on below case.

```
<span class="PostFull__reply"><a>Reply</a><!-- react-text: 276 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 277 --> <!-- /react-text --></span>
```

[image]

Comment: do you wan't to trigger the click event on the anchor tag?

Comment: The question not clear??

Comment: I hardly believe you didn't find anything about triggering link using JS... Could you please show that you actually tried something ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, how you can simulate `click` event programmatically (I have wrapped the function call in `setInterval` just for demonstration, the event will be fired every second):

```js
function clicked() {
  console.log('Clicked');
}

function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}

setInterval(function() {
  eventFire(document.getElementById('target'), 'click');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span class="PostFull__reply" id="target" onclick="clicked()"><a>Reply</a>
```